# Showing countable additivity for a pre product measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,S,\mu),{\,\,} (Y,T,\lambda)$ be two measure spaces. Let $\{A\}_{i\geq 1}, \{B_i\}_{ i\geq 1}$ be sequences in $S,T$ respectively such that for every two distinct positive integers $i,j\geq 1$ we have
$$ (A_i\times B_i)\cap (A_j\times B_j)=\emptyset$$
It is also given that there exists $A,B$  in $S,T$ respectively such that:

$$ \cup_{i\geq 1} (A_i\times B_i)=A\times B $$

Show that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_i)\lambda(B_i)=\mu(A)\lambda(B)$

I was able to show this only in the discrete case (where we have $A_1,A_2,...,A_n,\,\,\,B_1,B_2,...,B_n$). I feel it should be doable for the countable case but I didn't succeed in finding an argument.

Please do not use any of the theorems about product measures, Fubini's theorem as I am doing this to establish a pre product measure.

Thank you a lot.

This is NOT a homework question and I am not looking for full solutions. I welcome HINTS.

Comment: May I know why the down vote ? thank you

Comment: Is the question very easy ? I am OK with getting hints and I don't mind deleting the question if it is trivial. But so far I do not know the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learnt this solution from terence tao's blog.

Since $A\times B= \cup_{i\geq 1} (A_i\times B_i)$ and we have pairwise disjointness, therefore we know that for all $a\in A, b\in B$ we have:

$$1_A(a)1_B(b)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}1_{A_i}(a)1_{B_i}(b)$$
Thus, for every $a\in X$ we have:
$$\int_Y1_A(a)1_Bd\lambda=\int_Y\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}1_{A_i}(a)1_{B_i}d\lambda$$
$$1_A(a)\int_Y1_Bd\lambda=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}[1_{A_i}(a)\int_Y1_{B_i}d\lambda]$$
$$1_A(a)\lambda(B)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}[1_{A_i}(a)\lambda(B_i)]$$

The last step is justified by the monotone convergence theorem and linearity of integral. The last equation can be rewritten as an equation about functions $1_A,1_{A_1},1_{A_2},...$ because it holds for all $a\in X$:
$$1_A\lambda(B)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}[1_{A_i}\lambda(B_i)]$$
Applying the same trick again by integrating with respect to $\mu$ over $X$ we get:
$$\mu(A)\lambda(B)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}[\mu(A_i)\lambda(B_i)]$$

$\square$